# What are the situations where a function can't access global variables? And why?

Tags: javascript

I just run into this situation:

```js
var testing = 'thing 1';

function func() {
  console.log(testing);

  var testing = 'thing 2';

  console.log(testing);
}

func();
```

I expected the above code to log `'thing 1'` and only then `'thing 2'`. However, `'thing 1'` is never logged.

At first I thought it could be some behavior of static functions to reserve the `testing` variable to its scope, thus it being `undefined` instead of `'thing 1'`.

However, thinking more about it I'm not sure anymore if it is really a static function neither if my own explanation (which looked correct initially) is valid.

Why `testing` variable is `undefined` inside `func`? Why can't `func` access global variables? Are there any other situations like this?

PS: I tried to find a dupe, but failed.

Comment: welcome to hoisting

Comment: Hoisting in javascript - Creating confusion along with asyncronous stuff since 1995.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't get `thing 1` is because you are calling for `testing` from within the same scope that `testing` has a local definition. All declarations are **["hoisted"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)** to the top of their enclosing scope, so even though you wrote:

```
var testing = 'thing 2';
```

after your first `console.log()`, the `var testing` gets hoisted and processed as the very first bit of code in the function, so `testing` is declared locally, but not initialized yet (that will happen at the line's original location).

So, your code processes like this:

```
var testing = 'thing 1';      // 1. Runs as soon as encountered

function func() {
  var testing;                // 3. testing is hoisted and declared, but still undefined

  console.log(testing);       // 4. undefined is logged

  testing = 'thing 2';        // 5. local `testing` is now initialized

  console.log(testing);       // 6. local `testing` is logged "thing 2"
}

func();                       // 2. func is invoked
```

It's perfectly OK (but sometimes confusing) to have multiple variables with the same identifier (name), but what you must understand is that the smaller scopes are always checked first, so from within `func`, when you ask for `testing`, you will get the local version that "hides" the global one for the duration of that function.

Globals are called globals because you can always access them. If you want the global version, you can always access it as a property of the global `window` object:

```js
var testing = 'thing 1';

function func() {
  console.log(testing);

  var testing = 'thing 2';

  console.log(window.testing);
}

func();
```

Comment: @manuell Please don't edit someone's answer to fundamentally change the way it works. This was not a typo.

Comment: Very sorry about that. I thought you wanted to show how to get "thing 1" and then "thing 2", because that's what the OP wanted/expected...

Comment: @manuell In those situations, it's better to simply add a comment to the answer letting the person know that they may want to edit the answer, but you should never make an edit that changes the way the code works. I left it the way I did because my answer already explained hoisting and so `undefined` should be understood at this point in the answer. What really matters is the `window.testing` part.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript hoists all variable declarations that use `var` to the top of the function. So your function is behaving as if you wrote it like this:

```
function func() {
  var testing;

  console.log(testing);

  testing = 'thing 2';

  console.log(testing);
}
```